# Какую структуру данных нужно использовать?

Tags: java, android

Структура данных должна уметь добавлять объекты в свой конец. И удалять свои первые объекты. Т.е. первый зашёл - первый вышел. Количество запоминаемых объектов заранее не известно и меняется в ходе работы программы. Естественно время выполнения этих задач должно быть минимальным. Подскажите, какой структурой данных воспользоваться для решения поставленной задачи?

Comment: `первый зашёл - первый вышел`, это же очередь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO

Comment: @gil9red, я тоже предполагал, что это очередь. Но мне нужно узнать как называется эта структура данных в Java Android?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue

Comment: @ gil9red, посмотрел ваш совет. И понял, что видимо не точно сформулировал вопрос. Забыл указать, что программа должна иметь возможность произвольного доступа ко всем элемента структуры. Т.е. например, программа должна иметь возможность перебрать все элементы структуры с помощью for. А, насколько я понял, queue даёт возможность доступа только к самому первому элементу. Какая структура данных может работать как очередь, но даёт произвольный доступ к элементам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Queue это интерфейс](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue), чтобы с очередью поработать нужно использовать одну из множества его реализаций:

> AbstractQueue, ArrayBlockingQueue, ArrayDeque,
> BlockingDeque, BlockingQueue, ConcurrentLinkedDeque,
> ConcurrentLinkedQueue, DelayQueue, Deque,
> LinkedBlockingDeque, LinkedBlockingQueue, LinkedList,
> LinkedTransferQueue, PriorityBlockingQueue, PriorityQueue,
> SynchronousQueue, TransferQueue

Например [LinkedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList):

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
queue.add(1);
queue.add(2);
queue.add(3);
for (Integer x : queue) {
    System.out.print(x + " ");
}
System.out.println();
// 1 2 3 

System.out.println(queue.poll()); // 1
System.out.println(queue.poll()); // 2
System.out.println(queue.poll()); // 3
```